# Break the Transformer flow Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have spring integration flows. One for the file poller and other one is to process the file

**flow # 01**

poll the file in C:/testing directory

files comes goes to "process" queue

**flow # 02 (from "process")**

```
Transformer(new FindTheDepartItbelongs()) //basically file has to match to some depoartment
.transform(new FileParserTransformer()
.transformer(new CustomerTransformer()
.handle (o -> {})
```

The issue is if the `FindTheDepartItBelongs` cannot find the department then it has to stop the rest of the flow and send the message to some error queue.

If I return null from the transformer it does not work.

Is there any other way to achieve the same ?

Comment: Transformers can't return null; you need to show your complete flow configuration so we can help you with error handling configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell I already have error handler but I am interested to know if I can stop the flow in between?

Comment: A transformer cannot return null, but a `.handle()` method can and the flow just stops. It won't go to the error channel, though; you have to throw an exception for that.

Comment: @GaryRussell I got it mate . Thanks if you have sometime can you please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521593/taskexecutor-is-not-working-spring-integration

Comment: You can leave that as an answer if you want I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transformer cannot return `null`, but a `.handle()` method can and the flow just stops. It won't go to the error channel, though; you have to throw an exception for that.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.